# understanding 心配しなくとも in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence of two people drinking coffee/tea late at night:

> A:「悪くはないが……明日も授業があるだろ？」
> B:「ええ、勿論です。……心配しなくとも、寝坊などはしませんよ」

my understanding is that person B is saying "Don't worry, I won't oversleep" but I'm not sure how 心配しなくとも works here. is it similar to 心配しなくてもいい with the いい being omitted?

Answer (score 1):

とも attached to the 終止形 of a verb, or 連用形 of an adjective, has the meaning of 'even if'. It has a classical/literary flavour about it.

しなくとも = (modern Japanese) しなくても

するとも = (modern Japanese) しても